# Can't Deploy Drools Workbench to Tomcat because "repository root does not exist"

Tags: tomcat, drools

I have slowly been working through errors in the Drools Workbench deploy process, but I am stumped by this particular one.

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Repository root does not exist: repositories\kie
at org.guvnor.m2repo.backend.server.GuvnorM2Repository.getGuvnorM2Repository(GuvnorM2Repository.java:480)
at org.guvnor.m2repo.backend.server.GuvnorM2Repository.setM2Repos(GuvnorM2Repository.java:116)
at org.guvnor.m2repo.backend.server.GuvnorM2Repository.init(GuvnorM2Repository.java:96)
```

Can anyone help out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried setting a valid path for the M2 repository (user running application server must have write rights on this path) ? JBoss property looks like this :

```
org.guvnor.m2repo.dir=/tmp/repositories
```

Or in the xml version of the configuration :

```
<property name="org.guvnor.m2repo.dir" value="/tmp/repositories"/>
```

Tomcat configuration should be quite similar.

Comment: That was it. Thanks!

Comment: Where is this configuration store?